# cakephp 1.3 cross join tables in models

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a large application where I join tables in controllers,... here is one example

```
<?php
class HomeController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Home';

var $uses = array('User', 'UserRole', 'Friend', 'Photo', 'PhotoComment', 'PhotoTag', 'FriendRequest', 'Group', 'GroupDiscussion', 'Music', 'Blog', 'BlogComment', 'Dba', 'Video', 'VideoComment', 'Classified', 'Administration', 'Event', 'GroupFeaturedPoint', 'DbaFeaturedPoint', 'DbaPromoPoint', 'DbaLinkPoint', 'VideoFeaturedPoint', 'ClassifiedWeekpoint', 'ClassifiedMonthpoint', 'Recipe', 'Joke', 'RecipeComment', 'JokeComment');
```

and recently I start getting error: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 18087936) (tried to allocate 1024 bytes)... 
is there a way to join tables in a Models instead of Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 18087936) (tried to allocate 1024 bytes)

I've seen this type of error from CakePHP when it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

One source of this problem is Cake's own error handler. If there is an error while rendering the error view, then this can trigger an infinite loop.

To see what the original error was. You'll need to manually stop the error controller.

In your AppController.php file:

```
 function beforeFilter() {
     if($this instanceof CakeErrorController) {
         print_r($this->viewVars);
         die;
     }
     //.....
 }
```

The above will dump the error data to the browser, and stop the request. If it's an infinite error loop this will point you to the original cause.